# How do I use the std::find to find a set element with a struct member value?

Tags: c++, struct, set, find, std

```
struct Node{
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    Node(int newId,float newX,float newY,float newZ){id=newId;x=newX;y=newY;z=newZ;}
    bool operator<(const Node& rhs)const {return id < rhs.id;}
};
```

```
set<Node> graph;
Node a(1,2,3,4);
Node b(2,1,2,3);
Node c(3,4,5,6);
graph.insert(a);
graph.insert(b);
graph.insert(c);
```

I want to use the find function to find an element of `graph` with a certain id.
Something like `Node n = graph.find(3)` that would return an iterator to the element with id 3, x 4, y 5, z 6.
Currently the find function will only accept an initialized Node as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to use is `set<Node>::find()` rather than `std::find()`. You could easily do what you want with a function similar to `std::find()` - `std::find_if()`:

```
auto iter = std::find_if( graph.begin(), graph.end(), [](const Node& node){return node.id==3;});
```

The problem with this solution is that `std::find()` and `std::find_if()` have `O(n)` computational complexity (where `n` is the number of elements in the range), while using `set<Node>::find()` requires only `O(log(n))` complexity. You can achieve that if you slightly change your design (and you are using at least C++14).

First, use non-member `operator<` for struct Node, and add more comparison operators:

```
struct Node{
    int id;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    Node(int newId,float newX,float newY,float newZ){id=newId;x=newX;y=newY;z=newZ;}
};

bool operator<(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs)const {return lhs.id < rhs.id;}
bool operator<(const Node& lhs, int rhs)const {return lhs.id < rhs;}
bool operator<(int lhs, const Node& rhs)const {return lhs < rhs.id;}
```

Next, you need to use a set with *transparent* comparator:

```
std::set<Node, std::less<>> graph;
```

Now, what you are trying should work:

```
auto iter = graph.find(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use the std::find to find a set element with a struct member value?

> Currently the find function will only accept an initialized Node as an argument.

Strictly speaking, `std::find` doesn't have such requirement exactly. You can pass an object of any type that is comparable with the element type. That said, you may use `std::find_if` instead of `std::find`.

Note that `std::find_if` (like `std::find`) has linear complexity. If you want a data structure where finding an element based on related integer is efficient, then you'll want to use an associative map rather than a set.

Comment: `std::find` and `std::find_if` always have linear complexity - does not matter whether iterators have random access.

Comment: @Eugene Oh yea. Good point. I was thinking of `std::distance`. Answer fixed.